# How does snowflake encrypt files while performing internal staging?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Put command has no parameters relating to encryption. So where and how encryption takes place

Answer (score 0):

All files stored in internal stages for data loading and unloading operations are automatically encrypted using AES-256 strong encryption.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security.html

You may also want to check this:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption.html#end-to-end-encryption